# Modal Dialog Return Value is undefined - send result to parent window

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I fixed this issue before but I cant for the life of me remember how.

I need the return value to be sent to the parent window. I am currently using:

```
var rv = window.showModalDialog('blah.aspx', '', 'center:yes;status:no;scroll:no;help:no;dialogHeight:194px;dialogWidth:600px;');

document.getElementById("blah_ReturnValue").value = rv;

alert(rv);
```

Which is "undefined" in Chrome, but works fine in IE.

I have tried to set the `blah_ReturnValue` manually from the popup dialog with "sender.document.getelementsbyid" & "opener.document.getelementsbyid"

Not sure where to go from here as neither of them work, often resulting in Javascript errors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.opener.document.getElementById("blah_ReturnValue").value = rv;
```